# Estimate the number of prime power less or equal than $n$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Estimate the number of prime power (eg., $4=2^2$, $7$, $27=3^3$) less or equal than $n$. Any reference please?

By the Sqrt trick, every prime $\le \sqrt{n}$ contributes at most $log(n)$ times to the answer, and every prime $> \sqrt{n}$ contributes at most once, so the answer has the same order of $O(\frac{n}{logn})$. But any more sophisticated estimate please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number you are looking for is
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \pi(x^{1/m})
$$
where $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes not exceeding $x$.

As you mentioned, the primes not exceeding $\sqrt x$ contribute at most $O(\log x)$ times. Then we have
$$
\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\pi(x^{1/m})=O(\pi(x^{1/2})\log x)=O(\frac{\sqrt x}{\log x} \log x) = O(\sqrt x).
$$
The main contribution is the primes up to $x$. This is $\pi(x)$ and the current estimate is for some positive $c$,
$$
\pi(x)=Li(x)+O(x\exp(-c(\log x)^{3/5}(\log\log x)^{-1/5})).
$$
The error term is much bigger than $O(\sqrt x)$, hence
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\pi(x^{1/m})=Li(x)+O(x\exp(-c(\log x)^{3/5}(\log\log x)^{-1/5})).
$$
Under the Riemann Hypothesis, this error term becomes $O(\sqrt x \log x)$.